# Using iPod as a Mobile Battery Charger

Tags: power-supply, battery, ipod, ipod-touch, jailbreak

Is there anyway to make my (3rd gen i believe?) iPod touch output power? Preferably by a vanilla app, jailbreak, or another method that doesn't require tearing it apart. It current is sitting in my drawer collection dust, so I'd like to turn it into something at least somewhat useful.

Comment: No; there isn't,

Comment: @Ramhound And you know this because? I would appreciate some proof behind that statement.

Answer (score 2):

The USB Standard [USB On-The-Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) is the specification for devices needing an A-A or B-B type connection (i.e.: One that can supply current *or* draw current)

Ipods do not support this spec unfortunately. In cell phones it's implementation is limited to:

- BlackBerry Z30
- Nokia N8, C6-01, C7, Oro, E6, E7, X7, 603, 701 and 808
- Some Sony Xperia Android devices
- Some HTC Android devices
- Some Samsung Android devices

Android version 3.1 or newer supports USB On-The-Go, but obviously not on all devices.